# Model property not being passed back to OnPost method from Razor Page (Core)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, razor-pages

I am quite new to Razor Pages using EF Core and have a bit of a problem.

I have a model called Entry with a few properties...

[image]

On the Entry/Edit class, within the `OnGetAsync()` method, I am populating the Entry model to pass to the View. You can see here that the FishSpeciesId field is populated along with the other properties. All fine:

[image]

In my application, the value is passed through fine and displays as expected:

[image]

Without changing anything, I click the submit button to pass the Model back to the `OnPostAsync()` method, and all the properties in the model Entry are populated as expected except for the FishSpecies and FishSpeciesId.

[image]

Is there anything else I could check to see why I am seeing this specific value drop out of the Entry model? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are using [BindProperty] model for Entry class in razor page model.
something like this:

```
[BindProperty]
public EntryViewModel EntryModel { get; set; }
```

next make sure the properties you need in post back have been bound and used in your .cshtml file.

Comment: Thanks Majid. I have the Entry class with the [BindProperty] tag and believe the properties are bound as when the page loads the values appear as expected. All the values come back in the post except for the ones highlighted... Very confused.

Comment: Please share your .cshtml file here also.

Comment: I have just found that it looks like there is some Javascript kicking in and  causing this problem. I need to find out what exactly but when I take away the name and id from the cshtml input (used by some Javascript) then the values come through fine. I will investigate further and update.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out (yet not confirmed if this is a 'thing') that it seems I am not able to apply the name tag onto the input controls on the cshtml file.

[image]

When I removed the name attributes (which I thought were being used in Javascript - but are actually not) everything worked fine:

[image]

And I can see my FishSpecies values on GetPostAsync()

[image]

I would be interested to know if anyone else has noticed this or are a lot more familiar with how the Razor Pages work to explain what is going on here?